# Group letters of a sentence

Tags: python, group-by

I have a question about grouping letters in a string. For example, I want to group a sentence: my name is Jhon and I want something like this: myname ynamei nameis, and so on...
My code is:

```
def letters(siq,data):
    n=len(siq)
    for i in range(data -1, n -6, 1):
        yield siq[i:i+6]

test = 'My name is Jhon'
for i in range(1,4):
    print(list(letters(test,i)))
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Being able to identify and describe how your code fails to meet expectations is the first step towards being able to fix it yourself

Comment: "I have a question..." - namely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
test = 'My name is Jhon'
length = 6

test = test.replace(' ', '').lower()  # test = 'mynameisjhon'

data = []
for i in range(len(test) - length + 1):
    data.append(test[i:i+length])
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
['myname', 'ynamei', 'nameis', 'ameisj', 'meisjh', 'eisjho', 'isjhon']
```

---

if you want all possible groups of letters, whatever the length:

```
test = 'My name is Jhon'
test = test.replace(' ', '').lower()

data = []
for i in range(len(test)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(test) + 1):
        data.append(test[i:j])
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
['m', 'my', 'myn', 'myna', 'mynam', 'myname', 'mynamei', 'mynameis', 'mynameisj', 'mynameisjh', 'mynameisjho', 'mynameisjhon', 'y', 'yn', 'yna', 'ynam', 'yname', 'ynamei', 'ynameis', 'ynameisj', 'ynameisjh', 'ynameisjho', 'ynameisjhon', 'n', 'na', 'nam', 'name', 'namei', 'nameis', 'nameisj', 'nameisjh', 'nameisjho', 'nameisjhon', 'a', 'am', 'ame', 'amei', 'ameis', 'ameisj', 'ameisjh', 'ameisjho', 'ameisjhon', 'm', 'me', 'mei', 'meis', 'meisj', 'meisjh', 'meisjho', 'meisjhon', 'e', 'ei', 'eis', 'eisj', 'eisjh', 'eisjho', 'eisjhon', 'i', 'is', 'isj', 'isjh', 'isjho', 'isjhon', 's', 'sj', 'sjh', 'sjho', 'sjhon', 'j', 'jh', 'jho', 'jhon', 'h', 'ho', 'hon', 'o', 'on', 'n']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess the string by removing each space using `.replace()`, and then lowercasing the string using `.lower()`.

Then, to extract six-character substrings, you can use `zip()` along with list unpacking. This approach makes it easier to dynamically set the length of the substrings that you want to extract.

```py
data = 'My name is Jhon'
data = data.replace(' ', '').lower()
substring_length = 6
print(list(''.join(excerpt) for excerpt in zip(*[data[i:] for i in range(substring_length)])))
```