# Create a function without split in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function for agrupation 6 to 6 letters of a sentence, but without use split function.

My code is:

```
test="the world is mine today" 

def agru_letters(phrase):
    data = [] 
    for i in range(len(phrase) - 5):
        data.append(phrase[i:i+6])

print(agru_letters(phrase))
```

and the output that I want is:

```
['thewor',
 'heworl',
 'eworld',
 'worldi',
 'orldis',
 'rldism',
 'ldismi',
 'dismin',
 'ismine',
 'sminet',
 'mineto',
 'inetod',
 'netoda',
 'etoday']
```

Comment: You didn't return `data` from the function.

Comment: And if that is the actual expected output you need to remove all whitespaces prior to iterating.

Comment: `.split` would not help here anyway.

Comment: I write the 'return (data)' but only print me the first agrupation thewor.

Comment: I just realized that you appear to have asked the same question yesterday: [Group letters of a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180145/group-letters-of-a-sentence). Is this different in any significant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're expecting

```
test="the world is mine today" 

def agru_letters(phrase):
    data = []
    new = phrase.replace(' ', '')
    for i in range(len(new) - 5):
        data.append(new[i:i+6])
    return data
agru_letters(test)
```

Output:

```
['thewor',
 'heworl',
 'eworld',
 'worldi',
 'orldis',
 'rldism',
 'ldismi',
 'dismin',
 'ismine',
 'sminet',
 'mineto',
 'inetod',
 'netoda',
 'etoday']
```

Answer (score 1):

@PandasaPD beat me to it. I was busy adding steps and variable lengths.

```
def agru_letters(phrase, length=6, step=1):
  """
  return a list of 'words' of length length 
  that act like a moving window across the phrase 
  in jumps of step ignorening spaces
  """
  words = list()
  sanitized = phrase.replace(" ", "")
  for position in range(0, len(sanitized) - length + 1, step):
    words.append(sanitized[position:position+length])

  return words
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you didn't return `data` and you need to remove the spaces from the supplied string. Additionally, you attempt to call your function by supplying `phrase`, which isn't defined in your outer scope, which would throw a `NameError`. Fixing these issues:

```
test = "the world is mine today"

def agru_letters(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.replace(' ', '')
    data = [] 
    for i in range(len(phrase) - 5):
        data.append(phrase[i:i+6])
    return data

print(agru_letters(test))
```

You could also make the code's intent clearer using [`windowed`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.windowed) from more-itertools:

```
from more_itertools import windowed

test = "the world is mine today"

def agru_letters(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.replace(' ', '')
    data = []
    for i in windowed(phrase, 6):
        data.append(''.join(i))
    return data

print(agru_letters(test))
```

You might also consider making the length of substring an argument to `agru_letters`, and/or using a [list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) for brevity:

```
from more_itertools import windowed

test = "the world is mine today"

def agru_letters(phrase, length):
    phrase = phrase.replace(' ', '')
    return [''.join(i) for i in windowed(phrase, length)]

print(agru_letters(test, 6))
```

Comment: nice. windowed, that's a new one for me!

Comment: @AMG More-itertools is an incredibly useful package—I can't recommend it enough.